# Install PHP composer from a dockerfile

Tags: php, docker, installation, dockerfile, composer-php

I tried to install composer in a dockerfile using this code

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm
WORKDIR /app/php
RUN set update && set add curl && \
  curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer --version=2.0.2 | PHP
```

but when I exec the container I find that the composer isn't installed

```
root@70c:/app/php# composer -v
bash: composer: command not found
```

What's wrong?, and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

This will download the composer.phar file in the directory you are, in your case /app/php

If you want to have global access  to composer you should move it to /usr/local/bin directory and make it executable.

`chmod +x composer.phar`

`sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`